# Symfony, React: api/var/log/prod.log is empty on production server

Tags: reactjs, symfony, logging, production

`prod.log` file permissions are 0777

Logs are ok on localhost (docker, `api/var/log/dev.log`)

`api/config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
            #makes no difference excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
            buffer_size: 50 # How many messages should be saved? Prevent memory leaks
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
```

Production build is made using

```
npm run-script build
```

I've tried replace `api/config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml` by `api/config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml` but it did not help.

Anyone know please why `prod.log` is empty ?

EDIT

`vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php`

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */

public function getLogDir()
{
    return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/log';
}
```

`api/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php`

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getLogDir()
{
    return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/log';
}
```

Comment: Did you override the `App\Kernel::getLogDir()` method, if so what is in it?

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply. I'm sorry I don't know because I'm not author of the source code.

Comment: I have added source code of these methods to first post using EDIT